# Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent

Tags: android, android-emulator, appcelerator-titanium, android-9.0-pie

Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent

This is the latest SDK version I am selected to run my app:

`<sdk-version>8.0.2.GA</sdk-version>`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you please edit your question to include more details?

Comment: this is an error message when I am launching the android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I change my titanium SDK 8.0.2.GA to 7.4.0.GA.

Answer (score -1):

Update your sdk version, in settings->system settings->updates.
After updating the error will be resolved.

Comment: This answer needs context. What settings are you talking about?